# Key Error with form - DJANGO

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a project in django and I am creating a simple form that will allow a user to create a simple profile that asks for name and date of birth and location. I am getting a key error with the date of birth section and I dont know exactly why.

I am trying to collect data and store it to then later added it to a database record.

Here is the views file:

```
cd = form.cleaned_data
first_name = cd['first_name']
last_name = cd['last_name']
dob_month = cd['dob_month']
dob_day = ['dob_day']
dob_year = ['dob_year']
city = cd['city']
state = cd['state']
phone = cd['phone']
privacy = cd['privacy']
```

Here is the models file:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # server
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, default='first')
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, default='last')
dob_month = models.IntegerField(default=0)
dob_day = models.IntegerField(default=0)
dob_year = models.IntegerField(default=0)
city = models.CharField(max_length=45)  # user
state = models.CharField(max_length=25, default='state')
phone = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)  # user
privacy = models.SmallIntegerField(default=1)  # user
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)  # server
```

here is the forms file:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    split_choices = (('1', 'public'),
                     ('2', 'private'))
    privacy = forms.TypedChoiceField(
        choices=split_choices, widget=forms.RadioSelect, coerce=int
    )
    dob = forms.DateField(widget=extras.SelectDateWidget)
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'dob', 'city', 'state', 'phone', 'privacy']
```

and finally, here is the error that I am getting:

```
    KeyError at /setup_profile/
    'dob_month'
    Request Method: POST
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/setup_profile/
    Django Version: 1.8.6
    Exception Type: KeyError
    Exception Value:    
    'dob_month'
    Exception Location: C:\Users\OmarJandali\Desktop\opentab\opentab\tab\views.py in profile_setup, line 292
first_name  'omar'
last_name   'jandali'
dob_month   '1'
dob_day     '23'
dob_year    '2024'
city        'riverside'
state       'ca'
phone       '9515343666'
privacy     '1'
submit      'submit'
```

UPDATED:

here is the views.py file but the issue is with the cd['dobv_month'], but i have no idea why the error is coming from there.

```
def profile_setup(request):
    if 'username' not in request.session:
        return redirect('login')
    else:
        # the following is just going to grab the currently logged in user and
        # save the profile information to the appropriate user
        username = request.session['username']
        currentUser = User.objects.get(username = username)
        # the following is the provessing for the form where the user entered
        # the profile informaiton
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                cd = form.cleaned_data
                first_name = cd['first_name']
                last_name = cd['last_name']
                dob_month = cd['dob_month']
                dob_day = ['dob_day']
                dob_year = ['dob_year']
                city = cd['city']
                state = cd['state']
                phone = cd['phone']
                privacy = cd['privacy']
                # this is the new record that is going to be created and saved
                new_profile = Profile.objects.create(
                    user = currentUser,
                    first_name = first_name,
                    last_name = last_name,
                    dob_month = dob_month,
                    dob_day = dob_day,
                    dob_year = dob_year,
                    city = city,
                    state = state,
                    phone = phone,
                    privacy = privacy,
                )
                return redirect('home_page')
        else:
            # this is what is going to be saved into the html file and used to
            # render the file
            form = ProfileForm()
            message = 'fill out form below'
            parameters = {
                'form':form,
                'currentUser':currentUser,
                'message':message,
            }
            return render(request, 'tabs/profile_setup.html', parameters)
```

Comment: Use ModelForm instead of normal form.use DateTimefield for formfields dob_month,dob_day,dob_year

Comment: I didnt exactly understand what you are saying.. where should i switch ModelForm instead of form.use.. @EmilGeorgeJames

Comment: can you post your entire view file?

Comment: yeah i will have an updated section that will have the entire view..  the issue is just with the date of birth and processing that informaiton.... @MauricioCortazar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your model name is `User`.

`forms.py`:

```
from .models import User
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

and  `views.py`:

```
def user_create(request):
    form = UserForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST or None)
        if not form.is_valid():
            print form.errors
            return render(request, 'user_create.html', {'form': form})
        else:
            first_name = form.cleaned_data.get("first_name")
            last_name = form.cleaned_data.get("last_name")
            # pass your extra fields here
            new_user = User.objects.create_user(
                user=user,
                first_name=first_name,
                last_name=last_name,
                )
            new_user.save()
            return redirect('where you want to redirect',)    
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'user_create.html')
```

finally user will be save.

Read docs:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: the issue not with the first name and last name, it is the dob_month, dob_day, dob_year.... and i think the issue is in the forms.py file for the profile...

Comment: BTW. IT WORKED, I HAD TO USE `form.cleaned_data.get("dob_...)`. thanks emil... @EmilGeorgeJames